# Chrome. Remote debugging from connected Android Device: CORS issue

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, remote-debugging

I have a SPA running on my localhost:3000 and my ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API running on localhost:44372.

I'm trying to debug the SPA from my connected Android Device. I connected the device, did port forwarding, everything is well, SPA gets opened, but then it does a request to Web API and receives CORS error. When I check network tab I see that the origin is https://localhost:3000, which is correct. Does chrome remote debugging mode somehow replace the origin, because everything works well if I open the SPA locally?

I tried to debug Web API project with custom middleware, but I'm unable to hit the breaking point: seems like it returns CORS error before pipeline even started.

Here are my CORS configs in Web API:

```
builder.UseCors(x => x
                .WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3000")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials())
```

**UPDATE**

The CORS errors:
[image: 3 in 1]

**UPDATE 2**

I also forwarded the port 44372 which I have the Web API on and the error changed to: `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`. Is this an issue with the chrome on android? I'm not quite sure how to address it. The issue seems to be with the Web API server certificate, because SPA gets loaded properly.

Comment: Can you share the exact cors error?

Comment: @NickDawes, done

Comment: Nothing shown in https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Da9.png indicates a CORS error. Instead that just shows ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by opening `https://localhost:44372` on the Device. There I got a security warning, but when I chose "*proceed to localhost (unsafe)*" I was able to reach Web API. Then `https://localhost:3000` started working well.

Comment: Nice, who'd have thought.